# Update data from second table by other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables and I want to update the first table from second table by third table and fourth table.

The IDs in table1 & table2 are unique and the IDs in table3 & table4 are unique. In table2 & table3 uid is unique but I need to check another value too (source).

table1

```
| ID       | value          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | apple          |
| 2        | banana         |
```

table2

```
| ID       | uid            | source         |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 10             | tableA         |
| 2        | 11             | tableA         |
| 3        | 10             | tableB         |
| 4        | 11             | tableB         |
```

table3

```
| ID       | uid            | source         |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 5        | 10             | tableA         |
| 6        | 11             | tableA         |
| 7        | 10             | tableB         |
| 8        | 11             | tableB         |
```

table4

```
| ID       | value          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 5        | aaa            |
| 6        | bbb            |
```

I tried to run this query:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.source = 'tableA' 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.source = 'tableA' AND t3.uid = t2.uid 
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.ID = t3.ID SET t1.value = t4.value;
```

But I get error:
 `#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

What I wrote incorrect?

Comment: What about `bbb` which also matches to the 1st row of table1?

Comment: Yes, `bbb` to first row (uid==11). I have 10,000 rows. I wrote example here.

Comment: @amiad Had you created any indexes on your table? if yes could you show us?

Answer (score 0):

You can join all 3 tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.uid = t2.uid
SET t1.value = t3.value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have more table now, I edited my question.